# JWT Grant Built-in in PHP SDK?

Tags: docusignapi

I'm trying to make an integration with DocuSign. I found that the ApiClient has two built-in methods called '*requestJWTApplicationToken*' and '*requestJWTUserToken*', is there a way to use this to get authetication without having to implement any OAuth, only using the PHP SDK? I just need to get a token to send a envelope once in a while, not using indivual logins, my application manages the documents and dispatch.

I did all the pre-configuration needed such as, getting an integration key on the admin panel, as well as the RSA private key, but when i try to call the method 'requestJWTApplicationToken' i keep getting this error

> Error while requesting server, received a non successful HTTP code [400] with response Body: O:8:"stdClass":1:{s:5:"error";s:13:"invalid_grant";}

any ideas?

Comment: did you provide consent for the user to use the app?

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure of the following:
1. Your clientID is the IntegrationKey. They are one and the same. There's no clientSecret or secretKey required for JWT, only Auth Code Grant. 
2. UserId is provided. That's a GUID as well and should be the user that you are trying to impersonate (not the account!)
3. User provided consent. This is a one-time action for the user to authorize this app to make API calls on their behalf.
4. RSA Key is copy/pasted exactly the way (private key, not public) that it is in the admin console. Including the lines etc. Many issues are a result of a bad RSA Key